# Java Regex related search

Tags: java

I have one string `Hello java [to:] how are you?`. And I want output like: `Hello java how are you?`.

Please help with Java regex. My code is:

```
String data = "Hello java [to:sdsdsd.kdsd] how are you?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\[to:]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1))
```

Comment: please provide the code you have so far. This is not a code on demand page. Also be more specific as to what the expected behavior is.

Comment: String data = "Hello java [to:sdsdsd.kdsd] how are you?";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[to:]");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
  matcher.find();
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

Comment: don't post this in a comment, add it to the post.

Comment: Just use `String.replaceAll`

Comment: if i use data.replaceAll("[to:]",""); then its not working

Comment: how did you use that? most likely, it did work, but you did something wrong

Comment: @SomnathDutta when you tried replaceAll, did you remember to re-assign your data variable?

Comment: It is working When i use data.replaceAll("\\[to:(.*)]","")

Answer (score 0):

It is working When i use data.replaceAll("\[to:(.*)]","")